# apache flink - the correct way of error handling

Tags: apache-flink

I wonder if there is an option of built in error handling in Flink.
there may be 2 cases:

1. the current message from Kafka (in my case) is invalid, continue to next one
2. uncaught exception - from what I saw it can stop the stream aggregation completely.

ho can I handle these 2 cases? (java code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This is done idiomatically with a flatMap: if your message is valid, you go on with a list containing your valid element (maybe already processed in the same step). If it's not valid, you simply return an empty list so that no elements are produced by that step. I could provide Scala code but I'm not familiar with Java APIs so I don't want to put you off track. Just check the flatMap call.

2) This depends on the type of exception: if it's provoked by your own code, just catch it and handle it inside the operator, or simply log it and move on. Without any further information about a specific case, this is the best I know of, but again, coming from Scala I haven't experienced runtime exceptions.

Comment: thanks! about .1. my collect function gets a Tupple. can i call it with a null? will it work? or better not to call `collect` at all ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My answer was focused on the Scala API but clearly with the Collector in the Java API it's a bit different. You can avoid calling the `collect`, yeah.